# regex: lack of space at the end of the line makes mistake + remove tokens

Tags: java, regex

**I have the following regex:**

```
\s(_{1,2}).+?\1\s|\S+
```

**Test data:**

```
   _aa_a_    bb   _c__ d ee __  ff f_f__ g hhhhh_ _iiii- iiiii-ii-i_
jjjj k llllll      m   nnn oooo pppp qqqq _rrrr rrrr_
```

It parses my input string properly except the last words (rrrr rrrr). If I add a space at the end of the data it works fine.

1) How to modify my regex in order to the last 2 words will be processed properly without adding manually an extra space at the end of the line?

2) Another issue I have is that there is an extra space in the result and my tokens are not removed.

I can trim the result with Java but if possible I would like to get a perfect response that I do not need to post-process. But my main focus is on question 1. Q2 is nice to have :)

```
my result               I need to have this
-------------------------------------------
" _aa_a_ "              "aa_a"
"bb"
" _c__ "                "c"
"d"
"ee"
" __  ff f_f__ "        "ff"
"g"
"hhhhh_"
" _iiii- iiiii-ii-i_    "iiii- iiiii-ii-i"
"jjjj"
"k"
"llllll"
"m"
"nnn"
"oooo"
"pppp"
"qqqq"
"_rrrr"                  "rrrr rrrr"
"rrrr_"
```

[demonstration is here](https://regexr.com/548p1)

Comment: First issue is easy to solve, use `(?<!\S)(_{1,2}).+?\1(?!\S)|\S+`

Comment: I can accept your solution, please post it.

Comment: Ah, then it has already been answered.

Comment: You can use this regex for the first issue:\b(_{1,2}).+?\1\b|\S+